# Specific directory is forbidden

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

I'm using reverse proxy on my Ruby app- 2 to be exact - and the first instance which is located in "/var/www/cuba" works, but when I have a sub-domain to run another instance, I get this error(from error.log of Nginx):

```
2015/03/20 22:19:37 [error] 6813#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/blog/apps/web/public/" is forbidden, client: 174.60.38.101, server: blog.stackin.money, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "blog.stackin.money"
```

I tried adding permissions to www-data but I don't think that worked(if I even did it right)

The command was:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/blog/
```

Nginx Conf block:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
    server_name blog.stackin.money;
    root /var/www/blog/apps/web/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
    passenger_env_var LC_COLLATE en_US.UTF-8;
    passenger_env_var LANG en_US.UTF-8;
   }
```

Any help?

Comment: Post the nginx `server` block for the misbehaving application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added

Comment: @Apoph1s I'm posting it as an answer so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up [passenger_app_root](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerAppRoot) to the correct value.